# How to get right values from array thats values are in other table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the list of records saved as array in database like below:

```
---
- '9'
- '10'
- '11'
```

These are saved in `option_ids` column in table.

I have another table in which they all are present like below.

[image]

What I need to do is to print the values text like `speak well` if its id is present in `options_ids` column. So, what will happen is, if `options_ids` contains `9,10,12` etc so we will print data from other rows table like `speak well, read well, listen well`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your "other table" is class `OtherTable` and assuming your fourth column is called `text` then you'd want to do

```
options_ids.map{|option| OtherTable.find(option).text}.join(', ')
```

Comment: Thanks so much, you were so helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

When using rails you should take advantage of Active Record Associations.
I guess that a user(?) can choose different options from that second table.
The association would be a `has_and_belongs_to_many`-relation.

A good read is this section in the rails guide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association

Basically you set up a join table between users and options and tell the two models that they have a `has_and_belongs_to_many`-relation with each other.
Then when you fetch a user you can simple call user.options and it shows the options that are related to that user object.